# Can't Recurse Directories Properly

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to recurse directories in a c++ program I am creating using the QT creator application. For some reason, neither QDir::entryList nor QDirIterator seem to work. Using QDirIterator I can get the second directory down but it goes no further. A similar thing happens when I use QDir::entryList with nested foreach loops. Ultimately, I'd like to get the last directory, which contains no other directories, in a chain of directories.

This is intended to be cross-platform so it cannot be OS specific. I'd also like to avoid lots of switches for different OS' as I'd like to not have to work on it later and simply use it (potentially forever). I have tried foreach loops, while loops, anything I could think of.

QDir Code:

```
QStringList GetLastSubDirs(QDir baseDirectory) {
        QStringList result;
        baseDirectory.setFilter( QDir::Dirs|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );
        QStringList nonEmptyDirs(baseDirectory.path());
        while (nonEmptyDirs.size() > 0) {
            foreach (QString d, nonEmptyDirs) {
                QDir sd(d);
                foreach (QDir checkingDir, sd.entryList(QDir::Dirs|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot)) {
                    if (checkingDir.entryList().size() == 0) {
                       result.append(checkingDir.path());
                    } else {
                        nonEmptyDirs.append(checkingDir.path());
                    }
                }
                nonEmptyDirs.removeOne(d);
            }
        }
        if (result.size() == 0) {
            result = QStringList(baseDirectory.path());
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Here is the QDirIterator code:

```
class Directories
{
public:
        QStringList GetLastSubDirs(QDir baseDirectory) {
        QStringList result;
        baseDirectory.setFilter( QDir::Dirs|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );
        QDirIterator it(QDir::currentPath() + "/" + baseDirectory.path(), QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            QDir curWorkDir(it.path());
            curWorkDir.setFilter( QDir::Dirs|QDir::NoDot|QDir::NoDotDot );
            if(curWorkDir.entryList().size() >= 1) {
                foreach (QDir d, curWorkDir.entryList()) {
                    d.setFilter( QDir::Dirs|QDir::NoDot|QDir::NoDotDot );
                    if (d.entryList().size() <= 0) {
                        result.append(d.path());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                result.append(curWorkDir.path());
            }
            it.next();
        }
        if (result.size() == 0) {
            result = QStringList(baseDirectory.path());
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Debugger Output

```
1 Directories::GetLastSubDirs               main.cpp     56  0x555555559ba9 
2 Games::Games                              main.cpp     80  0x555555559f98 
3 __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 main.cpp     104 0x55555555931b 
4 _GLOBAL__sub_I_main.cpp(void)             main.cpp     120 0x55555555934e 
5 __libc_csu_init                                            0x55555555cd9d 
6 __libc_start_main                         libc-start.c 247 0x7ffff54ed270 
7 _start                                                     0x555555558f2a
```

Disassembler output:

```
0x555555558f00                  31 ed                 xor    %ebp,%ebp
0x555555558f02  <+    2>        49 89 d1              mov    %rdx,%r9
0x555555558f05  <+    5>        5e                    pop    %rsi
0x555555558f06  <+    6>        48 89 e2              mov    %rsp,%rdx
0x555555558f09  <+    9>        48 83 e4 f0           and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
0x555555558f0d  <+   13>        50                    push   %rax
0x555555558f0e  <+   14>        54                    push   %rsp
0x555555558f0f  <+   15>        4c 8d 05 aa 3e 00 00  lea    0x3eaa(%rip),%r8        # 0x55555555cdc0 <__libc_csu_fini>
0x555555558f16  <+   22>        48 8d 0d 33 3e 00 00  lea    0x3e33(%rip),%rcx        # 0x55555555cd50 <__libc_csu_init>
0x555555558f1d  <+   29>        48 8d 3d 74 01 00 00  lea    0x174(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555559098 <main(int, char**)>
0x555555558f24  <+   36>        ff 15 c6 70 20 00     callq  *0x2070c6(%rip)        # 0x55555575fff0
0x555555558f2a  <+   42>        f4                    hlt
```

I expect this particular snippet of code to recurse directories until it has cleared any directory that contains other directories. Instead it will only go down one level and stop. For some reason when querying the entryList().size() of these directories it always comes back with 0, even if the directory contains other directories, unless I include `.` and `..` and then it just loops forever because it wasn't intended to handle that.

Comment: You are modifying `nonEmptyDirs` inside a `foreach` loop over `nonEmptyDirs`.  That feels dangerous.  It certainly wouldn't work inside a C++11 ranged-for loop.  I suggest writing the `foreach` macro out by hand to check that it will work (in particularly, removing the entry in a list which the current iterator points to, is not going to end well.

Comment: If your problem is that the children of `baseDirectory` are always reported as empty, even when they are not, I suggest using a simpler example where you just report the number of grandchild directories in each child directory, and see if you can get that to work.

Comment: Also, if you save `sd.EntryList()` into a local variable, what does your debugger say is in it.?

Comment: When I saved ```entryList()``` to a variable and created a full backtrace I can't find it anywhere. Is there something else I need to do? I also looked at the global debugger log and didn't see anything either.

Comment: Yes.  Set a breakpoint in the debugger just after setting the variable.  Run the code.  When it breaks into the debugger, examine the variable.

Comment: added the breakpoint but I am very new to c++ and have limited knowledge about debuggers so I've included the output of both the debugger and disassembler. I can't edit my main post but that output was actually right on the line the variable is created (I guess I wasn't paying close enough attention. So here's a pastebin of the updated outputs: https://pastebin.com/cPVGFU4C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you make it so complicated. The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdiriterator.html) says this:

The QDirIterator class provides an iterator for directory entrylists.

You can use QDirIterator to navigate entries of a directory one at a time. It is similar to QDir::entryList() and QDir::entryInfoList(), but because it lists entries one at a time instead of all at once, it scales better and is more suitable for large directories. It also supports listing directory contents recursively, and following symbolic links. Unlike QDir::entryList(), QDirIterator does not support sorting.

The QDirIterator constructor takes a QDir or a directory as argument. After construction, the iterator is located before the first directory entry. Here's how to iterate over all the entries sequentially:

```
QDirIterator it("/etc", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << it.next();

    // /etc/.
    // /etc/..
    // /etc/X11
    // /etc/X11/fs
    // ...
}
```

**QDirIterator is already recursive when supplying QDirIterator::Subdirectories.**

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong all along. Instead of ```QDir curWorkDir(it.path());``` I should have used ```QDir curWorkDir(it.next());```. It still has a bug where it outputs a ton of random stuff but at least now it recurses properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`QDir::EntryList` returns the names of the child entries, not their full paths.  You need to append the name to the parent path to get the full path.

Given a hierarchy:

```
  basedir/
     child1/
     child2/
        grandchild1/
        grandchild2/
```

calling `entryList` on `baseDir` will return `["child1", "child2"]`, not `["basedir/child1", "basedir/child2"]`

---

As I said in the comments: I do not expect this code to work even when you fix that problem.  You are modifying `nonEmptyDirs` inside a `foreach` loop over `nonEmptyDirs`. That feels dangerous. It certainly wouldn't work inside a C++11 ranged-for loop. I suggest writing the foreach macro out by hand to check that it will work.  In particularly, removing the entry in a list which the current iterator points to, is not going to end well.

Comment: tried modifying the paths to include the working directory but that didn't seem to solve anything with QDir. I've moved back to ```QDirIterator``` and tried the same fix (adding the working directory) and now I just get a bunch of ```child 1 child 1 child 1 child 1```

Comment: That's the code I am using now. Note that ```it``` is the QDirIterator and looks like so: ```QDirIterator it(QDir::currentPath() + "/" + baseDirectory.path(), QDirIterator::Subdirectories);```. Everything besides one while loop being changed for another is the same as the previous example.

Comment: I suggest either [edit]ing your question to include your updated code (as well), or asking a new one.  Putting this in comments is pretty much unreadable.

Comment: Don't use currentPath + "/" + path.  - Use absolutePath to get it directly (and correctly).

Comment: Apologies. I added the code to the original post. With the path changed to absolutePath I actually get more ```child1 child1 child1```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html) ... last sentence most important

> Qt automatically takes a copy of the container when it enters a foreach loop. If you modify the container as you are iterating, that won't affect the loop. (If you do not modify the container, the copy still takes place, but thanks to implicit sharing copying a container is very fast.)
>
> Since foreach creates a copy of the container, using a non-const reference for the variable does not allow you to modify the original container. It only affects the copy, which is probably not what you want.